# Raspberry pi not getting any data from hx711

Tags: raspberry-pi, load-cell, board, python

I'm trying to combine two boards into one: SparkFun Load Sensor Combinator(basically just a wheatstone bridge) and SparkFun Load Cell Amplifier. The data will be transmitted to a Raspberry Pi 3 so there is a connector on the board specifically to communicate with the raspberry. My problem that nothing is comming out the HX711. Nothing comes out of DATA nor CLOCK. Here is the schematics i've done:
[image: Schematics]

I've tested the transistor to make sure it's saturated because i thought that may be the wheatstone bridge was not correctly powered but it's ok. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Get a scope or cheap USB/sigrok logic analyzer and verify that the pi is sending the appropriate signals.  The clock of an HX711 is an *input* not an *output* - so *software* your host system will have to drive that.  You might want to test the setup with a premade HX711 board first, if this is a custom build consider not only design errors but subtle soldering ones too.

Comment: Actually I own the original boards and using them my program works. This means the signals are ok right ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use electrical test equipment and or careful inspection by eye (perhaps with magnification) to figure out what the difference between the working stock boards and your non working custom ones is.

Comment: The clock is an *input* to the unit.  I suspect nothing happens on the data line until you provide a clock.